# Access AWS Secrets Manager with IMDSv2 set to required

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I'm working on a Java application running on an EC2 instance in AWS. My goal is to access AWS Secrets Manager using an AWS SDK for Java and an IAM role attached to the EC2 instance.

Everything works smoothly when IMDSv2 (Instance Metadata Service version 2) is optional. However, when it's set to required as recommended, I encounter an issue.

Specifically, I'm receiving the error `'software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain'`.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully access AWS Secrets Manager with IMDSv2 set to required?

Tried attaching different policies, created some custom ones but the result is same.

java sdk version used:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
     <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
     <version>2.25.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using a very old version of the AWS Java SDK? Minimum versions are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/use-a-supported-sdk-version-for-imdsv2.html).

Comment: No, I am using the newer version
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.7</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I'd check that the effective user that your Java app is running under can retrieve credentials via IMDSv2. Maybe SSH into the EC2 instance and use curl as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-metadata-v2-how-it-works.html) to generate a token and then fetch the credentials.

Comment: I did do that, and was able to retrieve the metadata items by using the command given, so it's just something that needs to be added / modified to make sure the sdk also connects

Comment: Refer to the AWS Java DEV guide about credentail providers. Your issue is the app cannot find your keys. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue but this issue only appears with IMDSv2 set as required on the ec2 instance and not when it is set as optional (working as expected in that case) and there is nothing regarding IMDSv2 on the documentation.

Comment: Here is a doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration-imds.html if you are migrating from IMDSv1 to IMDSv2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and was able to figure this out. There have been issues with IMDSv2 network request and what was suggested is to increase the hop limit to '2' on the ec2 instance. As said here in the considerations section as well https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#imds-considerations

To increase the hop limit:
"Use the modify-instance-metadata-options CLI command and set the http-put-response-hop-limit parameter to the required number of hops. In the following example, the hop limit is set to 2. Note that when specifying a value for http-put-response-hop-limit, you must also set http-endpoint to enabled"

Using aws cli:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options \
--instance-id <instance-id> \
--http-put-response-hop-limit 2 \
--http-endpoint enabled
```

Comment: Are you saying that you're running containers on EC2? You didn't mention that in the original question.